# Resource Dictionary doesn't style buttons in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dictionary, user-controls

When my application is launched the buttons background is not set. All the buttons are placed in a UserControl. My resource dictionary lives in its own project and is called by the following code in the App.xaml.

```
 <Application.Resources>

    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/UMLDiagram.Windows.Theme;component/Theme.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>


        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Model:ClassData}">
            <Canvas>
                <View:ClassDataUserControl/>
            </Canvas>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Model:Connector}">
            <Canvas>
                <View:ConnectorUserControl/>
            </Canvas>
        </DataTemplate>

    </ResourceDictionary>

   </Application.Resources>
```

The code from the UserControl looks like this:

```
 <UserControl x:Class="UMLDiagram.View.SidePanelUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="240">

 <StackPanel Width="240">
    <Label Content="TOOLBOX" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Stencil" Foreground="#FF355BAE"/>
    <GroupBox Header="File" Foreground="White" Margin="6" Height="91">
        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,30">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="27*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Content="Open" Command="{Binding OpenCommand}" Margin="6,4,6,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="26" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="2"  Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Margin="6,4,6,0" Height="26" VerticalAlignment="Top" ></Button>
            <Button Content="Save As.." Command="{Binding SaveAsCommand}" Margin="56,40,56,-26" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1"></Button>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
    <GroupBox Header="Undo / Redo" Foreground="White" Margin="6">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="27*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Content="Undo" Command="{Binding UndoCommand}" Margin="6,4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="2"  Content="Redo" Command="{Binding RedoCommand}" Margin="6,4"></Button>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
    <GroupBox Header="Class Diagram" Foreground="White" Margin="6">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Add Class" Command="{Binding AddClassDataCommand}"></Button>
            <DataGrid x:Name="classDataControl" Height="140" ItemsSource="{Binding ClassDatas}" HeadersVisibility="Column" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Number}" Header="ID" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ClassName}" Header="Class Name" Width="*"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <Button Content="Remove Class" Command="{Binding RemoveClassDataCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=dgClassData}"></Button>         
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
    <GroupBox Header="Relations" Foreground="White" Margin="6">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Add Relation" Command="{Binding AddConnecterCommand}"></Button>
            <Button Content="Remove Relation" Command="{Binding RemoveConnecterCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=dgEdges}"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
    <GroupBox Header="Zoom" Foreground="White" Margin="6">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Content="In" Command="{Binding ZoomInCommand}" Margin="6,4" ></Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="1"  Content="Out" Command="{Binding ZoomOutCommand}" Margin="6,4"></Button>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
    <StackPanel.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="#B8C3CF"></SolidColorBrush>
    </StackPanel.Background>
  </StackPanel>
 </UserControl>
```

I can not see why it dosn't work - the dictionary should be okay

Am I missing something in my UserControl or App.xaml?

Thanks,
Mikael

Comment: [how to use an Application Resource Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348820(v=vs.110).aspx) have you checked out this link by chance..?

Comment: Nothing immediately stands out.  Theme.xaml is in the root directory of the other project? Does the Button style definition in Theme.xaml contain an "x:Key" definition?  Can you post the relevant markup from Theme.xaml?

Comment: Thank you everybody for your help - the solution was actually quite clear: I didn't have any x:Key definition in my Button style. Also, I needed the 'StaticResource ResourceKey=buttonBrush' attribute at my buttons.